# How can I draw an axis with values on some points?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I think the figure is very simple.

[image: example]

Nevertheless, I can't figure out how to do it. Any help?

Comment: Related (but more advanced usage) question: [Creating a line of given length with variable number of “snags” equally separated (TikZ)?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30015/creating-a-line-of-given-length-with-variable-number-of-snags-equally-separate)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A very basic approach just to show the concept.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (6,0);
    \foreach \x/\xtext in {0/a,1/b,3/c,6/d}{
      \draw (\x cm,-2pt) -- (\x cm,2pt) node[above] {\xtext};
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For details you should take a look into the »[pgf/tikZ](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf)« user guide.

---

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I prefer an answer instead of a long comment but I want to say that it's preferable to use the same method to work with dimensions

If you wrote  `\draw (0,0) -- (6,0);` then the code would be :

```
 \documentclass{minimal}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (6,0);
    \foreach \x/\xtext in {0/a,1/b,3/c,6/d}{
      \draw (\x ,-.08) -- (\x,0.08) node[above] {\xtext};
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

A problem  can appear if later you use `scale = 2` or `x= 2 cm, y = 2 cm` or if you want to use big numbers.

Why is important :

```
 \documentclass{minimal}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0)--(600,0);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

gives an error Latex Error : ... Dimension too large.

```
 \documentclass{minimal}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.01 cm]
  \draw (0,0)--(600 cm,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

gives the same error

but

```
 \documentclass{minimal}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.01 cm]
    \draw (0,0)--(600,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document} 
\end{document}
```

is correct. a dim is limited by 16 384 pt near 5.75 m but TeX can work with big numbers, the next code compiles but you can't replace `x=0.00001 cm` by `x=0.000001 cm`

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.00001 cm]
 \coordinate (x) at (600000,0);
  \draw (0,0)--(x);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A very interesting aspect. Good to know.